# android -no certain line that indicate what is causing error

Tags: android

this is very strange ,I've tested it on 2 phones and it has no problem but my friend get this error:

```
STACK_TRACE = java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 4, size is 2
at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getItem(ArrayAdapter.java:337)
at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:390)
at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
at android.widget.Spinner.makeAndAddView(Spinner.java:395)
at android.widget.Spinner.layout(Spinner.java:346)
at android.widget.Spinner.onLayout(Spinner.java:310)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11390)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4332)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1653)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1642)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1418)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11390)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4332)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1653)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1511)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1416)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11390)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4332)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:444)
at android.widget.ScrollView.onLayout(ScrollView.java:1405)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11390)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4332)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:444)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11390)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4332)
at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:743)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11390)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4332)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1653)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1511)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1416)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11390)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4332)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:444)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11390)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4332)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1653)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1511)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1416)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11390)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4332)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:444)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11390)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4332)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1490)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2455)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:817)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

There is no line that points to a certain line on the activity . How can I solve this problem when I don't know which activity and which line has the error ?

could you help me ?

Thanks

Comment: How many ListView do you have in your application ?

Comment: In the STACK TRACE there is a part that begins with 

    Caused by Exception ....
    At SampleActivitiy...
    At Sample Activity...

That's the part that shows what line is causing the error. Do you not have that at all? Search for "Caused by" in the trace of the exception.

Comment: @BenyaminNoori thanks for reply ,I don't have any sample activity .

Comment: Dude, I know that! That's an example. Search for "Caused by" in your stack strace.